# LinqPad - Type missing

Tags: vb.net, linqpad

I've created the following VB Statement:

```
Dim str1 As [String] = "indigo"
Dim str2, str3 As [String]

MessageBox.Show("str1 = '{0}'", str1)

MessageBox.Show("str2 = Upper case copy of str1 using English-United States culture.")
' str2 is an upper case copy of str1, using English-United States culture.
str2 = str1.ToUpper(New CultureInfo("en-US", False))

' str3 is an upper case copy of str1, using Turkish-Turkey culture.
MessageBox.Show("str3 = Upper case copy of str1 using Turkish-Turkey culture.")
str3 = str1.ToUpper(New CultureInfo("tr-TR", False))
```

Added System.Globalization.dll via Query Additional References but the execution fails with Type 'CultureInfo' is not defined.

How do I solve this?

Stefan

Comment: You need the namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by SLaks in comments, you need to import the namespace `System.Globalization` :

> Query > Namespace Imports (or Ctrl+Shift+M)

On the other side you don't need the reference to System.Globalization.dll as [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is in mscorlib.dll so already referenced.
But you probably need one to use [MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or instead use another way to print things, like a `Console.WriteLine` or the "LinqPad specific" `Dump`)